# Android relative layout and hide a child that other view defines to be above it

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout that has 2 children.
The first child has `android:layout_above="@+id/other_child”`
I see that if the second child is invisible my layout is working fine.
But is this safe?
What I am trying to do is if the second child is visible to have the first above the other.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation seems fine, but the easy way would have been using a linear layout (even in terms of performance).

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, would you please accept it?

Comment: You say it should work but don't elaborate on this. I already know that it works because as mentioned in OP I tested it. My question is if there is any case that this could fail or it is valid to expect that if the view defined to be bellow something and is hidden the layout renders properly